# How do I implement oAuth 2.0 in Google App Engine with RESTEasy?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am developing a Google App Engine REST service and I want to use oAuth 2.0 for authentication. I added the following code to my service methods to check for a valid user and it works in that it throws an exception when I am not authenticated.

```
try 
{
    final OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
    final User user = oauth.getCurrentUser();
}
catch (final OAuthRequestException e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Now I want to authenticate against this with command line programs that are written in Java and Python.

I have spent hours searching Google and StackOverflow both and I can't find a single lucid example of how to authenticate against my GAE application with a non-browser application that makes any sense. I found lots of examples on how to authenticate against Google's own API's but nothing about authenticating against my own Google App Engine application.

Can someone provide a instructions on how to authenticate against a Google App Engine application with either Java or Python?

Comment: I had so much of the same problem that I gave up and went with basic HTTPS/SSL/Session Cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

I finally got OAuth 2.0 working on my Google App Engine application. I have uploaded some example command line tool client code to my GitHub account. It is way too much code to publish here in code boxes. I will update this answer when I do a complete blog post about how I got it working and how the code works.

#### RESTEasy

Use the code posted in my question to access the `User` that is authenticated as the first thing in each service method, it will throw and exception if the user isn't authenticated.

#### Credits

Thanks to [Fábio Uechi](http://fabiouechi.blogspot.com/) for posting some code that mostly worked and just needed some updating. I did more than a little updating and refactored it out a good bit from [what he had done](http://fabiouechi.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-google-oauth-java-client-to.html).